# How to email variable value using raspberry pi and smtplib

Tags: python-2.7, smtp, raspberry-pi3

I am working on this project where i have 3 string variables which I want to email their values to an email address. I was able to email a plain text message; however, I couldn't include these variables values in. Below is my codes:

```
import serial
import smtplib
import time

serialport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout = 0.5)
user= 'user@gmail.com'
password= 'password'
receiver= 'receiver@gmail.com
subject= 'Solar tracker status'
header = 'To: ' + email + '\n' + 'From: ' + email + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + 
subject
while True:
    line = serialport.readline()
    result = line.find(";")
    if result > 0:
            str = line.split(";")
            volt=str[0]
            power=str[1]
            temp=str[2]
            body = "\n" + + "Voltage: " + volt + "\n" + "Power: " + power + "\n" + "Temp: " + temp
            print header + '\n' + body
            s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
            s.ehlo()
            s.starttls()
            s.ehlo()
            s.login(email, password)
            s.sendmail(email, email, header + '\n\n' + body)
            s.quit
```

When running this script, i got this error message :

```
File "testserial.py", line 23, in <module>
    body = "\n" + + "Voltage: " + volt
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

I have tried converting the variable into string using str(volt), then got this error message:

```
File "testserial.py", line 23, in <module>
    str(volt)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I can't understand this because they are originally in string format since i was able to write them into a text file using %s without having to convert it.

I think i just don't know how to pass a variable into the body of the email. 
Please help!

Comment: You see the double-`+` typo `"\n" + + "Volt` in line 23 right?  Remove one of them, for starters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kingsley! It works now, I should have double checked for typo.

Comment: How do i vote for your answer? sorry I'm new

Comment: It's not an answer, just a comment ;)  Don't worry about it... glad I could help.